# Using Deep Neural Networks to detect the position bolts/nuts in an CAD-Model

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

i am trying to use Deep Neural Network to detect the position of nuts and bolts in CAD-Models. I exported the CAD-Model as .stl and loaded it into matlab

[image]

[image]

the next step is to train the Neural networks to detect the position of the nuts. Here i dont know where and what to start with.

I know how to use Deep Neural Networks on images. But i have no idea on how to use it on CAD-Models therefore i need some help

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: To me the data looks like connected line segments. Is the stl file just a huge list of coordinate pairs, each pair defining a line? Perhaps you could load an stl file into an interactive plot, click to label the nut locations (on 3 planar views), and write that back out to a file that has a label of 1/0 for each line segment that corresponds to a nut. That information could be used to train a network, which will learn the line patterns associated with nuts and their locations. This is just a high-level overview of what I might start experimenting with in terms of developing a training set.